# Erro de Lock Conflit FIREBIRD

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, transações

Sou novo quanto ao assunto Banco de Dados, então espero que entendam minha dúvida e falta de conhecimento:

Utilizamos o Firebird como SGDB e o IBExpert como ferramenta para administração e configuração do Banco de Dados. Por conta da aplicação em questão ser utilizada simultaneamente por vários usuários (realizando operações de UPDATE, DELETE e INSERT na mesma tabela praticamente) ocorrem erros de lock conflict. 
Eu havia lido que ao aguardar alguns minutos a transação se solidifica (ou parando o Serviço do Banco de Dados e o iniciando novamente) e também há a opção de rodar o comando abaixo.

```html
gfix -commit all
```

Porém, minha pergunta é: Existe algum comando que possa ser executado no IBExpert por exemplo, e que confirme essas transações na hora da execução, já que a conexão com o Banco de Dados seria remotamente, e não na máquina do Servidor para conseguir rodar o comando citado acima?

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O IBExpert não tem acesso as transações feitas no banco.
Para commitar, vai depender da aplicação que está usando o banco mesmo.

É possível resolver o *lock conflict* dando *shutdown* na base e tornando para *online* novamente ou reiniciando o Firebird. Nos dois casos, é derrubado as conexões e consequentemente as transações.

Porém é um procedimento de risco, visto que você está encerrando a conexão com o banco. E caso no momento alguém esteja realizando alterações algum dado, há possibilidade de corromper.

Ao menos até onde sei.
Aguarde por mais um tempo para vermos se alguém tem uma resposta melhor.